# Visual Studio Console Debug Popup

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, logging, .net-core

I've been running some Quickstart samples from IdentityServer4 and found that when I run a web site (e.g. the IdentityServer)... a popup shows up with messages... I am assuming it's either a logger window or the console output... but I have poked around and have no idea how this is done.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a default console logger

Comment: @pavel-anikhouski any idea how to turn it on or off?

Answer (score 0):

So... I quickly made a project called test as an example... and in the Properties/launchSettings.json... there were two items under profiles (IIS Express and test)... then when I choose this project there is now, in 2019 at least (maybe I never noticed it before), a new combo box where I can choose between IIS Express and test... when I choose IIS Express it just shows the browser... but when I choose test it shows the browser and a command box with I believe console debugging info.

This maybe be referred to as Self Hosted, but not 100% sure.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52015",
      "sslPort": 44344
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```